# Does the Forge API support 2-legged bearer tokens for Bim360 Team hub types?

Tags: autodesk-forge

The Forge API works like a champ for Bim360 Docs hub types using 2-legged bearer token. However, I can't find documentation that confirms whether or not 2-legged authentication works for Bim360 **Team** hubs. Can anyone confirm this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data Management API to access BIM 360 Docs hubs using 2 legged OAuth, which is intended for background automation. You may consider adding the `x-user-id` header to enforce permissions.

Comment: How about Bim360 Team hubs?

Comment: BIM 360 Teams is moving to BIM 360 Docs.